# WPF Item Templates - TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, templates, xaml

I am writing an application in which I utilize a tab control which will start with one tab open but allows the user to open multiple other tabs.

Each tab that is openned should have a treeview inside which I fill using databinding when the user loads a file.

I am new to WPF but I feel as if there is a way in which I can create a template containing each of the elements the TabItems should contain. How can I do this using templates? Right now my WPF for the tab items is the following

```
<TabItem Header="Survey 1">
        <TreeView Height="461" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="625" Margin="0,0,6,0" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeviewDataSelector}" />
 </TabItem>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
        <TreeView Height="461" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Width="625" Margin="0,0,6,0" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeviewDataSelector}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListThatPowersTheTabs}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}">
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

You basically create re-usable templates as static resources which you refer to by their key name.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in this sort of situation I bind my `TabControl.ItemsSource` to a `ObservableCollect<ViewModelBase> OpenTabs`, so my ViewModel is in charge of adding/removing new tabs as needed.

Then if you want something in every Tab, then overwrite the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` and use the following line to specify where to display the currently selected TabItem

`<ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />`

If you don't need to setup something in every single tab, you don't need to overwrite the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` - it will default to displaying the currently selected `ViewModelBase` in the Tab.

And I use DataTemplates to specify which View to use

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TabAViewModel}">
    <local:TabAView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TabBViewModel}">
    <local:TabBView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TabCViewModel}">
    <local:TabCView />
</DataTemplate>
```